# Python class argument repetition

Tags: python, list, class, arguments

I am writing a bit of Python code to use a list to store order data. Is there any way to avoid having to repeatedly use the same arguments?

```
import datetime, pickle

class Order:

    def __init__(self, order_number_legacy, platform, value, user_id):
        self.order_number_legacy = order_number_legacy
        self.platform = platform
        self.value = value
        self.user_id = user_id

    def match(self, order_number_legacy):
        return filter in self.order_number_legacy

    def print(self):
        return f"{self.order_number_legacy}, {self.platform}, {self.value}, {self.user_id}\n"    

class Orders:

    def __init__(self):
        self.orders = []

    def newOrder(self, order_number_legacy, platform, value, user_id):
        self.orders.append(Order(order_number_legacy, platform, value, user_id))

    def save(self):
        with open("orders.data", "wb") as fh:
            pickle.dump(self.orders, fh)

    def load(self):
        with open("orders.data", "rb") as fh:
            self.orders = pickle.load(fh)

    def print(self):
        text = ""
        for order in self.orders:
            text += order.print()
        return text
```

You can see that I have several instances of the arguments "order_number_legacy, platform, value, user_id". Once I have added all of the Order class variables, the code will have lots more arguments repeated. I would have thought Python would have a way to "tidy" this up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for `Order`. It'll automatically take care of the `__init__` function:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Order:
    order_number_legacy: int
    platform: str
    # ...
```

Comment: Great, does the job perfectly. Is there something similar I can do with the newOrder function?
`    def newOrder(self, order_number_legacy, platform, value, user_id): 
        self.orders.append(Order(order_number_legacy, platform, value, user_id))`

Comment: You can either use `locals()` and ignore `self`, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997999/432733, or use `kwargs` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42507706/432733.

Comment: I went with the `*args` option. This is great as it saves me adjusting lots of code when adding a new variable to the class.

Comment: How would I declare an empty list in the Order class that is not included in the arguments? `@dataclass
class Order:
    order_number_legacy: int
    platform: str
    log: List[Log]`

Comment: This appears to work:`order_number_legacy: str
 platform: str
 value: str
 user_id: str
 name: str
 logs: List[Log] = Logs()`

Comment: Okay, I have sussed it now. The @dataclass works perfectly. If needing to add any other variables not referred to in the arguments use `def __post_init__(self):` and add the variables as they normally would be entered under `def __init__(self):`